# How to make and link when building a C executable from large C++ library

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I am a beginner in C and slightly more advanced in C++. This is my first time using `make`.

I have a large C++ library (written by a third-party that I need to integrate into a C pipeline) and I am hoping to call this library from C. In order to call the C++ library from C, I have 3 files: a `.cpp` file implementing the calls to the C++ library with C-compatible data types, a `.h` C-compatible header file linking the C++ implementation functions to C, and a `.c` file with a `main()` function that calls the C++ function with C-appropriate data types.

The header file (`random_forest.h`):

```c
#ifndef RANDOMFOREST_H_
#define RANDOMFOREST_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */

// opaque forward declared struct
struct random_forest_model;

// pointer to struct used by C code
typedef struct random_forest_model* random_forest_model_t;

random_forest_model_t random_forest_new(const char* model_file_path);

void random_forest_free(random_forest_model_t random_forest_model);

uint8_t *classify(
    random_forest_model_t random_forest_model,
    const double* independentVariableData,
    const double* dependentVariableData,
    const size_t numberRows,
    const size_t numberColumns,
    const char** independentVariableNames
);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */

#endif /* RANDOMFOREST_H_ */
```

In my `random_forest.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include <memory.h>
#include "/src/random_forest.h"
#include "/src/rf/src/Forest.h"
#include "/src/rf/src/globals.h"
#include "/src/rf/src/ForestClassificationPrediction.h"
#include "/src/rf/src/utility.h"

using namespace rf; /* comes from Forest.h file */

struct random_forest_model {
  std::unique_ptr<rf::Forest> forest;
  std::string model_file_path;
}

namespace {
    std::unique_ptr<rf::Forest> random_forest_acquire(const char* model_file_path) {
        try {
            std::unique_ptr<rf::Forest> forest = make_unique<ForestClassificationPrediction>();
            forest->InitPredictionModelCpp(model_file_path);

            return forest;
        } catch(...) {
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
} /* anonymous namespace */


random_forest_model_t random_forest_new(const char* model_file_path) {
    try {
        auto forest = random_forest_acquire(model_file_path);
        return new random_forest_model{std::move(forest), model_file_path};
    } catch (...) {
        return nullptr;
    }
}


void random_forest_free(random_forest_model_t random_forest_model) {
    delete random_forest_model;
}


uint8_t* classify(
        ranger_random_forest_model_t ranger_random_forest_model,
        const double* independentVariableData,
        const double* dependentVariableData,
        const size_t numberRows,
        const size_t numberColumns,
        const char** independentVariableNames
) {
    try {
        /* bunch of stuff here to convert data and run classification */
    } catch(...) {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Then in my `random_forest_implement.c` file:

```c
#include "/src/random_forest.h"

int main() {
    const char model_file_path[] = "path/to/model";
 
    random_forest_model_t random_forest = random_forest_new(model_file_path);

    /* 
    some code here to ingest a data file - outputting the data for random_forest_classify
    yielding: X, y, numberRows, numberColumns, varNames 
    */

    uint8_t *classes = classify(
        random_forest, X, y, numberRows, numberColumns, varNames
    );

    random_forest_free(random_forest);

    free(X);
    free(y);
    free(varNames);
    free(classes);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is a very long-winded way to ask how to compile this program into a single executable. I've tried to compile with the following `make` file:

```
CC ?= gcc
CP ?= g++

random_forest_implement: random_forest_implement.o random_forest.o
    $(CP) -o random_forest_implement random_forest_implement.o random_forest.o

random_forest.o: random_forest.cpp random_forest.h
    $(CP) -c random_forest.cpp

random_forest_implement.o: random_forest_implement.c random_forest.h
    $(CC) -c random_forest_implement.c random_forest.h

clean:
    $(RM) *.o random_forest
```

When I try to make this (`make -f random_forest_make.mk`), I get three lines that appear (?) successful, and I receive a lot of errors about `undefined reference`, e.g.:

```
cc -c random_forest.c random_forest.h
g++ -c random_forest.cpp
g++ -o random_forest_implement random_forest_implement.o random_forest.o
/usr/bin/ld: random_forest.o: in function `(anonymous namespace)::random_forest_acquire(char const*)':
random_forest.cpp:(.text+0x44f): undefined reference to `rf::Forest::InitPredictionModelCpp(<bunch of args necessary to method>)
```

I'm not entirely sure where to go from here, but I suspect I'm not compiling everything correctly. As you can see, I have several files on which my `random_forest.cpp` file depends. Do I need to compile each of these? And their dependencies? Is there a best/efficient method for doing this, or do I need to write a `make` file that generates an object file for every `.cpp` file in the `/src/rf/src/` directory?

Comment: You have to put the _definitions_ of the functions you want to be C compatible inside `extern "C"` as well, not just the _declarations_.  So add that to your `.cpp` file.  Also I assume you have a typo in your header file where you declare the function to be named `classify` rather than `random_forest_classify` as you have in the C++ file.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing out that typo; indeed that was the case. Re: `extern "C"`, I'm referecing the write-up here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#cpp-objs-passed-to-c, in which the `.cpp` does not need `extern "C"` so long as the header file declares it so. This is incorrect?

Comment: `$(CP) -o random_forest_implement random_forest_implement.o random_forest.o` does not link against your "large C++ library (written by a third-party that [you] need to integrate into a C pipeline)".

Comment: @CopyOfA Your usage of `extern "C"` in the header file and not on the function definitions themselves is correct, assuming `#include "src/random_forest.h"` in your posted C and C++ code actually refers to the `random_forest.h` file contents you posted.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes, that's correct, the `random_forest.h` file is included in both `.c` and `.cpp` files. Re: your first comment -- I guess this may be my question. How should I link these libraries? Do I need to `make` objects for every `.cpp` file in the `/src/rf/src` directory? How do I include those objects in the `make` file?

Comment: Can you link to the library with the `-l` and `-L` options?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot build a C executable including C++ sources. You can only create C++ executables if you include any C++ code. C++ supports C source modules to be linked against for compatibility reasons but C compilers were not designed to link C++ modules (there’s no backwards compatibility between C and C++, C was created before)

For this reason, you can only use c++ compiler to link C++ mixed with C sources (even if main is defined in a C source file) because this action will make C++ compiler to call the linker in C++ mode and link both C/C++ modules and call the C++ standard library modules and run time. Despite of the similarities between both languages, the memory layout of a C++ executable is more complex than the layout of a simple C-only program

Comment: I'm confused by this assertion, given [this write-up](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#cpp-objs-passed-to-c). Am I to conclude that an executable compiled from this code would not work? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're saying; am I supposed to compile C++ sources separately? This seems true, but I'm unsure about the specific procedure for this.

Comment: You will receive an error if e.g. you try to link your program containing .o files coming from c++ source files, as the compiler will select the wrong linker, with no support for class initializers or improper runtime modules. IMHO gcc has overcome this, but as a general rule, once you have a source module in c++, just switch the whole program into C++ mode, as you will need it.

Comment: The code of @CopyOfA to build the executable is correct, he uses each compiler frontend to make the compilations, but at the time of linking the `.o` files, he uses `g++` only, as probably using `gcc` for linking would lead to the error I comment above.